# Dynamically expanding table from object array

Tags: javascript, jquery

As the title states, I'm trying to create a table that will dynamically expand or shrink depending on the number of objects in the array. Each of these objects has 10 properties which all need to be displayed in separate rows. I started writing the for loop to iterate over the array and display each property using JQuery's .html() and realized it would look messy when all said and done, but I do not know where to start.. The complete code is below, but I'm working in the showResults function now..

```
//scripts
//Customer Object constructor
function CustomerObject(fName, lName, mName, address, city, state, zip, age, gender, pizza) {
    this.fName = fName;
    this.lName = lName;
    this.mName = mName;
    this.address = address;
    this.city = city;
    this.state = state;
    this.zip = zip;
    this.age = age;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.pizza = pizza;
}

//Array of CustomerObjest
var CustomerArray = new Array();

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#TBFName").focus();
});

$("#BtnSave").click(function () {
    //When Save button is pressed.

    Validate();
}); 

$("#BtnReset").click(function () {
    //When Clear button is pressed
    ClearAllInfo();
});

$("#BtnDone").click(function () {
    //When Done button is pressed
    ShowResults();
});

$("#BtnMore").click(function () {
    //When Enter More button is pressed
    ShowResults();
    $("#DivFormContainer").show();
    $("#DivResults").hide();
});

$("#BtnMoreClearCustomers").click(function () {
    //When Clear All Customers button is pressed
    CustomerArray = new Array();
    $("#DivFormContainer").show();
    $("#DivResults").hide();
});

function Validate() {
    var isValid = true;
    var fstName = $("#TBFName").val();
    var mdlName = $("#TBMI").val();
    var lstName = $("#TBLName").val();
    var addrs = $("#TBAdress").val();
    var cit = $("#TBCity").val();
    var stat = $("#DDState").val();
    var zipCode = $("#TBZip").val();
    var gend = $("input:radio[name='RGGender']:checked").val();
    var old = $("#TBAge").val();
    var pza = $("input:radio[name='RGLikePizza']:checked").val();
    // Validation goes Here for All Fields


    if (isValid == true) { //If isValid is still true, no errors
        CustomerArray.push(new CustomerObject(fstName, lstName, mdlName, addrs, cit, stat, zipCode, old, gend, pza));
        $("#DivMessage").show();
        $("#DivMessage").html("Record Saved. Add a new record or press done to see results.");
        $("#DivMessage").fadeOut(1600);
    }
}


function ShowResults() {
    ClearAllInfo();
    $("#DivResults").show();
    $("#DivFormContainer").hide();
    //Code to display all customers information
    for (var i = 0; i < CustomerArray.length; i++) {

        $("#list").html(CustomerArray[i].fName + CustomerArray[i].lName +      CustomerArray[i].mName);
        //create table?
    }
}

function ClearResultsDiv() {
    $("#DivResults").html("");
}

function ClearAllInfo() {
    $("input[type=text]").val("");
    $("textarea").val("");
    $("select").prop('selectedIndex', 0);
    $(".error").html("");
    $("input[type=radio]").attr('checked', false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is where direct DOM manipulation becomes messy and you are better off using an MVC framework. There are many to choose from: http://todomvc.com

I made a quick example using [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nuGwz?editors=101

The nice thing is, you then only need to care about modifying your data (the customer array). The view (DOM) gets updated automatically. Like so:

```
$scope.CustomerArray.push({name: 'Joanna', age: '46', city: 'New York'});
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you want to generate a table from an array containing row data.

Here's one way to make a table:

```
var maketable = (function(){

    var elem, td, th, tr;

    elem = function(elemtype, children){
        var el = document.createElement(elemtype);
        children.forEach(function(child){
            el.appendChild(child);
        });
        return el;
    };

    td = function(s){
        return elem('td', [document.createTextNode(s)]);
    };

    th = function(s){
        return elem('th', [document.createTextNode(s)]);
    };

    tr = function(row){
        return elem('tr', row.map(td));
    };

    return function(data){
        var cols, rows, thead, tbody, table;
        cols = Object.keys(data[0]);
        rows = data.map(function(row){
            return Object.keys(data[0]).map(function(key){
                return row[key];
            });
        });
        thead = elem('thead', [elem('tr', cols.map(th))]);
        tbody = elem('tbody', rows.map(tr));
        table = elem('table', [thead, tbody]);
        return table;
    };
}());
```

Example usage:

```
var data = [{a: 'a0', b: 'b0'}, {a: 'a1', b: 'b1'}, {a: 'a2', b: 'b2'}];
var table = maketable(data);
document.body.appendChild(table);
```